# How can I remove a website from the exceptions list for a plugin on Mozilla Firefox that is set to "ask to activate"?

Tags: firefox, youtube, flash-player, browser-plugin

I normally have Mozilla Firefox ask me before activating shockwave flash on 
account of a slight bit of instability I notice when I tried to use YouTube. I 
have it set to "allow and remember" on most websites, the main exception being 
YouTube. Recently, however, I accidentally clicked "allow and remember" instead 
of "allow now" on YouTube because I was tired and it had been a long day. Is 
there any way to remove YouTube from the exceptions list without simply clearing 
the exceptions list? I'm using Firefox version 29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `about:config` page and change `devtools.chrome.enabled` to `true`.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to open Scratchpad and switch Environment to Browser.

Copy and paste the following code

```
var ytprincipal = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptsecuritymanager;1"]
  .getService(Ci.nsIScriptSecurityManager)
  .getNoAppCodebasePrincipal(Services.io.newURI("http://www.youtube.com", null, null));
Services.perms.removeFromPrincipal(ytprincipal, "plugin:flash");
```

Click Run and you 're ready!

Comment: I understand most of that, but where do I find what you call "about:config"?

Comment: Type `about:config` at the address bar and press Enter.

Comment: The solution doesn't work. Not in Firefox 29 at least: Cc is not defined. Yes, I've set devtools.chrome.enabled to true.

Comment: @Zore switch Environment to Browser

Comment: @macks2008 Did you switch Environment to Browser?

Comment: @paa How do I do that?

Comment: The menu bar of Scratchpad has a drop-down menu named Environment

Comment: @paa Wait, I just checked your answer again. Is it somewhere in Scratchpad's menus?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I saved that JavaScript for future use should I make the same mistake again.

Comment: I would rep+ this answer, but I only have 11 reputation on this website. Guess I better go answer some questions :-)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the site whose plugin settings you want to change:

- Right click anywhere on the page and select "View Page Info"
- Go to the "Permissions" tab
- Select which plugins should allow/block/ask.